# New uploads not refreshing to Advanced API call (Vimeo Plus Account)

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

How long should I expect to wait until a video I uploaded to an album shows up through my API call?
It has been 3 hours since the "processing" on Vimeo was completed, and it's still not showing up. It only shows up on the Vimeo website directly.
I am on a Vimeo Plus account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are making an authenticated API request to see your own list of videos, and you were the user who uploaded the video, you should see the video as soon as you have completed the upload.

Basically if you can see it on site, you should see it in the API.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't using OAuth to make my call. I added the authentication to my request and now I see my uploads immediately.